# How to set Weblogic Spring 2.5 application context path?

Tags: spring-mvc, configuration, weblogic

The idea is to automatically have:

```
http://localhost:7001/myApp/
```

instead of:

```
http://localhost:7001/myApp
```

Thanks for anyone helping me.

**EDIT :** 
I think expressed myself wrong.
Actually, I just want to 'force' browser to be redirected to (localhost:7001/myApp/) when it tries to get (localhost:7001/myApp). In other words, adding a slash so that css, js, links load properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved this issue by manually adding the context path, this way:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="windows-1252"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> 
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%
        String context = request.getContextPath();
    %>
```

... further in my jsp and wherever I need:

```
<a href="<%=context%>/manageUnavailabilities?requestType=create">
```

The result is that I have links like these:

```
http://localhost:7001/myApp/manageUnavailabilities?requestType=create
```

Instead of:

```
http://localhost:7001/myAppmanageUnavailabilities?requestType=create
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to set the `context-root` value for your application. You'll want to edit your application.xml file in your .ear or your weblogic.xml file in your .war and add:

```
<weblogic-web-app>
    <context-root>myApp/somethingElse</context-root>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Reference the Oracle docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/webapp/weblogic_xml.html#wp1073750)

Many similar questions have been asked, see [Application Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843594/how-can-i-use-weblogic-12-c-without-the-application-context-in-the-url)

BTW - your question needs to be edited, you pasted the same URL twice but I got the gist of the question.

Comment: ​Thanks for replying, I think expressed myself wrong, actually, I just want to 'force' browser to be redirected to (localhost:7001/myApp/) when it tries to get (localhost:7001/myApp). In other words, adding a slash so that css, js, links load properly.

Comment: I have something similar in the application.xml as follows: `<module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>vip-webapp-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>vipWebapp/</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>` The second link in your answear shows how to do the opposite. I hope you'll understand better :)